# Replace coefficient list with new coefficient list

Tags: coefficients

I would like to replace all the coefficients with new conditions in a list that I specify.

For example, suppose I have the polynomial $a_1 x + a_2 x^2$.

```
p = a1 x + a2 x^2;
CoefficientList[p,x]
```

Returns the list `{0,a1,a2}`. I would like to replace this list from the greek alphabet ($\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \dots$) such that in this case it replaces the old coefficients with {0, $\alpha, \beta$}.

Thanks for your help!

***EDIT:***

In general the polynomial occurs with differences between polynomials and so I end up with (a1 + b1 + c1)x + (a2 + b2 + c2)x^2. I would still like to be able to replace this as $\alpha x + \beta x^2$.

Comment: what would be desired result for the input `p1 = 3 + a1 x +2 x^2+  a2 x^3`?

Comment: I would want it to become $p1 = 3 + \alpha x + \beta x^2 + \gamma x^3$

Comment: No matter what will be the structure of the coeffs, it they are constant ,i.e., independent of other variables, the current answers will be helpful...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, which one in particular. I tried working with kglr's answer and
greekCoeffList[(a1 - b1) x + a2 x^2] returns {$\beta, \epsilon, \zeta$}, where it should return {0, $\alpha, \beta$}

Comment: Oh, So others except that from @kglr  ;)),  however, I am sure he/she correct it soon, after your comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[greekCoeffList]
greekCoeffList = Module[{cl = CoefficientList[#, x]}, 
  cl[[2 ;;]] = Symbol /@ FromCharacterCode /@ Range[945, 945 + Length[cl] - 2]; cl] &;
```

Examples:

```
cl2 = greekCoeffList[a1 x + a2 x^2]
```

> {0, α, β}

```
Expand @ FromDigits[Reverse @ cl2, x]
```

> x α + x^2 β

```
cl2 = greekCoeffList[(a1 + a2) x + (b1 - b2) x^2]
```

> {0, α, β}

```
Expand @ FromDigits[Reverse @ cl2, x]
```

> x α + x^2 β

```
cl2 = greekCoeffList[3 + a1 x + 5 x^2 + a2 x^3]
```

> {3, α, β, γ}

```
Expand @ FromDigits[Reverse @ cl2, x]
```

> 3 + x α + x^2 β + x^3 γ

Comment: This module seems to get confused if for example I have (a1 + a2) x + (b1 - b2) x^2

Comment: I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Gregory,  please see the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that the number of your coefficients is less than the number of Greek alphabet letters:

```
p = a1 x + a2 x^2;
oldcoef = CoefficientList[p, x];
newcoef = Join[{First@oldcoef}, Take[EntityValue[Entity["Alphabet", "Greek::33sff"], 
EntityProperty["Alphabet", "CommonAlphabet"]], Length[oldcoef] - 1]]
```

$$\{0,\alpha ,\beta \}$$

so:

```
FromDigits[Reverse@newcoef, x]
```

$$\beta  x^2+\alpha  x$$

If you need more letters, just add to the list more characters corresponding to other languages, or those in uppercase style of the Greek language:

```
EntityValue[Entity["Alphabet", "Greek::33sff"], 
EntityProperty["Alphabet", "CommonAlphabetUpper"]]
```

$$\{A,B,\Gamma ,\Delta ,E,Z,H,\Theta ,I,K,\Lambda ,M,N,\Xi ,O,\Pi ,P,\Sigma ,T,\Upsilon ,\Phi ,X,\Psi ,\Omega \}$$

Answer (score 1):

Treating the constant special makes things a bit messy..

```
 (MapIndexed[ 
      Boole[# =!= 0] x^(#2[[1]] - 1) FromCharacterCode[943 + #2[[1]]] &,
      CoefficientList[#, x]  ] /. 
          FromCharacterCode[944] -> Coefficient[#, x, 0] // Total) &@
       (3 + 2 x + 3 x^5)
```

> [image]